# How to check domain is verified using Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, verification

I have used `analytics.read` in order to get user's sites and Google API response is:

```
{
    "kind": "analytics#accountSummaries",
    "username": "user@gmail.com",
    "totalResults": 1,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "itemsPerPage": 1000,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "92159597",
            "kind": "analytics#accountSummary",
            "name": "MyNewDomain",
            "webProperties": [
                {
                    "kind": "analytics#webPropertySummary",
                    "id": "UA-92159597-1",
                    "name": "MyNewDomain",
                    "internalWebPropertyId": "236529827",
                    "level": "STANDARD",
                    "websiteUrl": "http://www.example.com",
                    "profiles": [
                        {
                            "kind": "analytics#profileSummary",
                            "id": "140745434",
                            "name": "All Web Site Data",
                            "type": "WEB"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Why there is no property related to domain status? How should I check whether domain is verified or not?

I tried to use `siteverification` scope for Google Verification API, it has the response that I need and it returns the list of verified domains but it has a scope of managing domains, so no one will actually grant access to our application in order to manage their domains and verify/un-verify domains.

Sample response:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "site": {
    "type": "string",
    "identifier": "string"
  },
  "owners": [
    "string"
  ]
}
```

How can I use `analytics.read` to get verified domains not unverified websites?

Comment: When you say whether a domain is verified, what exactly do you mean? You are querying the Google Analytics API which has information about the data sent to it via https requests, (either through client side Google Analytics JS or the Measurement Protocol)

Comment: @sdhaus I need to create a service that verifies user ownership of a domain. I want to make sure he owns that domain using GA. I have used `Google Site Verification API` for now and don't know how can I accomplish it using GA or even is it possible?

Comment: Its not possible to verify domain ownership using GA.